# Mocking Task.Delay

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a method with the following line: `await Task.Delay(waitTime).ConfigureAwait(false);`

I there a good strategy to avoid actually waiting the few seconds when unit testing and instead verify that we tried to wait a specific number of seconds.

For instance, is there a way to inject an additional parameter into my method like in this (contrived) example where I inject a mocked object of a fictitious `ITaskWaiter` interface:

```
// Arrange
var mockWait = new Mock<ITaskWaiter>(MockBehavior.Strict);
mockWait.Setup(w => w.Delay(It.Is<TimeSpan>(t => t.TotalSeconds == 2)));

// Act
myObject.MyMethod(mockWait.Object);

// Assert
mockWait.Verify();
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can define a "delayer" interface like this:

```
public interface IAsyncDelayer
{
    Task Delay(TimeSpan timeSpan);
}
```

And then you can provide the following implementation for production code:

```
public class AsyncDelayer : IAsyncDelayer
{
    public Task Delay(TimeSpan timeSpan)
    {
        return Task.Delay(timeSpan);
    }
}
```

Now, your class would look something like this:

```
public class ClassUnderTest
{
    private readonly IAsyncDelayer asyncDelayer;

    public ClassUnderTest(IAsyncDelayer asyncDelayer)
    {
        this.asyncDelayer = asyncDelayer;
    }

    public async Task<int> MethodUnderTest()
    {
        await asyncDelayer.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

        return 5;
    }
}
```

This is basic application of [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). Basically, we extracted  the logic of asynchronously waiting to a different class and created an interface for it to enable [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)).

In production, you would compose your object like this:

```
var myClass = new ClassUnderTest(new AsyncDelayer());
```

Now, in your test you can create a fake delayer that returns immediately like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task TestMethod1()
{
    var mockWait = new Mock<IAsyncDelayer>();

    mockWait.Setup(m => m.Delay(It.IsAny<TimeSpan>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(0));

    var sut = new ClassUnderTest(mockWait.Object);

    var result = await sut.MethodUnderTest();

    Assert.AreEqual(5, result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is the correct approach.

##### Alternative 1

If you want to "hide" the dependency from client code (in different assemblies), but allow tests to use it:

```cs
public class ClassUnderTest
{
    private readonly IAsyncDelayer asyncDelayer;

    public ClassUnderTest() : this(new AsyncDelayer()) { }   // used by client code

    internal ClassUnderTest(IAsyncDelayer asyncDelayer)      // used by tests
    {
        this.asyncDelayer = asyncDelayer;
    }

    public async Task<int> MethodUnderTest()
    {
        await asyncDelayer.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        return 5;
    }
}
```

##### Alternative 2

If you don't want to introduce the mockable dependency (for whatever reason), then extract the delay to a `virtual` method and mock that:

```cs
public class ClassUnderTest
{
    internal virtual Task Delay(TimeSpan delay) => Task.Delay(delay);

    public async Task<int> MethodUnderTest()
    {
        await Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        return 5;
    }
}
```

In the test, you need to partial mock the class. Then mock `Delay()` to return `Task.CompletedTask` so it does nothing. You can also verify that the mocked method was called with the value `2`.