# How to unit test method that uses await delay

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have created dummy code to describe my issue as follows:

```
  public class ItemGenerator
    {
        public bool isStopped;
        public List<int> list = new List<int>();
        public void GetItems(int itemsPerSecond)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (!isStopped)
            {
                list.add(i);
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }



    [Test]
    public void TestGetItmes()
    {
        ItemGenerator gen = new ItemGenerator();

        gen.GetItems(1000);

        await  Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            gen.isStopped = true;
            Assert.True(gen.list.Count() == (5 * 1000));
        });
    }
```

Now the problem is that the assert will fail sporadically, I guess it's to do with CPU performance and the fact that there is no guarantee that delay of 1000 will be always 1000ms but what would be the best approach to UT this kind of logic ?

Comment: Your `GetItems` method should be awaited (so it should return a task). And so should your test (`public Task TestGetItmes()`)

Comment: Probably a failure of your example, but you cant possibly use `await` in `GetItems` as it is not `async`

Comment: Maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537996/mocking-task-delay

Comment: @Iqon yeah i saw that and was wondering if this is the way to go....

Comment: @IronHide static framework methods are always problematic in unit testing. If the project is big enough, I always wrap those methods in helper services. (IoC and DependencyInjection will make this a lot easier). Otherwise, most of those methods aren't testable at all. I mean, you could wait for 10 seconds, but unit tests are supposed to be fast. If you can mock the method, you can reduce the time to zero.

Comment: yeah but lets say i can wait whatever e..g 1h in the test, this does not work anyway because there is no guarantee that two delays of 1H will finish at the same it is it ? So I guess i will have to mock the time :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would approach this - firstly use the built in `CancellationToken`

```
public class ItemGenerator
{
    public List<int> List { get; } = new List<int>();

    public async Task GetItems(CancellationToken token)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            List.Add(i);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Then your test can make use of `CancellationTokenSource` and specifically `CancelAfter` method:

```
var gen = new ItemGenerator();

CancellationTokenSource src = new CancellationTokenSource();
src.CancelAfter(5000);
await gen.GetItems(src.Token);
```

Note you could pass the `CancellationToken` in to the constructor of `ItemGenerator` instead of the method if that is more appropriate.

Comment: OK but there is still no guarantee that the number of items will match expected value since the delay in the test vs delay in the  method may not be equal ? My main issue is that the result differ and i assume that it's due to the fact the the delay itself fluctuates.

Comment: Seriously there should be a rule that forces user to provide feedback for negative votes. Otherwise what is the point ?